# PHPStorm presentation mode left margin

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Any idea how I can customise the size of the left hand margin when in presentation mode?

[image]

On a 27" monitor this is absolutely huge!

I've had a look through the settings and couldn't find anything, any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue -- please vote/star/comment to get notified on progress (hopefully will be fixed for v8):

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126090

Comment: Thank you, really hoping it gets fixed for the next release!